# Descargar todo el tema de wordpress a NetBeans desde un servidor de GoDaddy

Tags: wordpress, netbeans, wordpress-theme

Estoy tratando de descargar un tema que le agregue a mi sitio de WP pero no puedo descargarlo a NetBeans, puedo descargar los otros temas pero no este y tienes los mismos permisos desde el servidor.
Ayuda por favor

Comment: has probado descargar desde FTP ? Si descargar otro ciente FTP te da lata, te recomiendo este que se integra con Firefox https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fireftp/ :D

Comment: Con FTP si puedo descargar todo, el problemas es cuando quiero descargarlo a algun IDE para hacer los cambios directo al servidor, pero en filezzilla si puedo hacer FTP normal

Comment: con que sistema operativo trabajas?